# Are this prototype inside the class function constructor?

Tags: javascript, class

```
class Person {

    constructor(name) {

        this.name = name;
        }
    }
    
    methodProto() {
        console.log('hello pro ' + this.name);
    }
    
}
```

Is ***methodProto*** a prototype of Person function constructor?
If not , then what is it , sorry i am still learning , so i might sound stupid....

Comment: `methodProto` is a method (a function of an object), not a prototype.

Comment: "methodProto" is the name of a property on `Person.prototype`, and the value of that property is that little function.

Comment: but if its a function , wouldnt it be declared inside 
``` constructor(name) {.....} ```

Comment: May you explain? Inside what?

Comment: inside teh constructor keyword? or is it a function? i mean just inside it , like how this.name is a property of that object , like that we can also do 
``` this.methodInside = function() {....} ```

Comment: If a function is declared inside the constructor it will not exist on the class prototype object.

Comment: but just now , one of the answers , showed by accessing it with prototype method

Comment: @001Wolf right, because it is **not** declared inside the constructor.

Comment: Also note that the Person class has **one** prototype. The prototype is where the collection of class instance methods goes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - see:

```js
class Person {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  methodProto() {
    console.log('hello pro ' + this.name);
  }

}

console.log(Person.prototype.methodProto);
```

The ES class syntax is just mostly syntactic sugar. This exists for backwards compatibility.

Comment: May you explain why?